# How can I convert a keyword to a string?

Tags: clojure

In clojure, what is the idiomatic way to convert a keyword:

```
:some-keyword
```

to a string:

```
"some-keyword"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use **name** to do this:

```
user=> (name :some-keyword)
"some-keyword"
```

Answer (score 2):

As Alex Ott mentionned, **name** is the best function for this, *clojure.contrib* also has a function you can call on any type: **as-str** which does this too:

```
(str :foo :bar)     ;;=> ":foo:bar"
(as-str :foo :bar)  ;;=> "foobar"
```

See 
http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/string-api.html#clojure.contrib.string/as-str